# Cannot program NDSolve for two-variable system of ODE

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, dynamic, nonlinear

Please help program a system of 2 ODEs:

\begin{cases} \frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{df}{d{(x+y)}} \\ \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{df}{d{(x+y)}})+\frac{df}{d{(x+y)}}=0 \end{cases}

where $f=-(x+y)^2$

There is my code and error message:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

extr = -(x[t] + y[t])^2

sys = 
 NDSolve[{x'[t] + y'[t] == D[extr, x'[t] + y'[t]], 
   D[D[extr, x'[t] + y'[t]], t] + D[extr, x'[t] + y'[t]] == 0, 
   x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 500}]
```

**ERROR:**

```
During evaluation of In[672]:= General::ivar: (x^\[Prime])[t]+(y^\[Prime])[t] is not a valid variable.

During evaluation of In[672]:= General::ivar: (x^\[Prime])[t]+(y^\[Prime])[t] is not a valid variable.

During evaluation of In[672]:= General::ivar: (x^\[Prime])[t]+(y^\[Prime])[t] is not a valid variable.

During evaluation of In[672]:= General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[672]:= NDSolve::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. NDSolve will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations.

During evaluation of In[672]:= NDSolve::nlnum: The function value {0. -\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(0.`\)]\((\(-4.`\))\)\),\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(0.`\)]\((\(-4.`\))\)\)+\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(0.`\)]0.`\)} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {2} at {t,x[t],y[t],(x^\[Prime])[t],(y^\[Prime])[t]} = {0.,1.,1.,0.,0.}.

During evaluation of In[672]:= NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.
```

Comment: I think you will have to calculate the derivative with respect to the sum yourself. For instance, since you want to differentiate with respect to $q = (x+y)$, then you can express $f$ as a function of that $q$, such that $f=-q^2$. You can differentiate that with respect to `q`, then back-substitute the value of `q`: `df = D[-q^2, q] /. q -> (x[t] + y[t])`. You could then use `df` wherever you need the derivative of f with respect to (x+y).

Comment: @MarcoB,Write your comment as answer, please.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the relevant mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note this is not a coupled system of ODE's. The two equations even contradict each other.

You could write f as a function of one variable, then you get the following equations:

```
f[z_] = -z^2;
eq = {x'[t] + y'[t] == f'[x[t] + y[t]], D[f'[x[t] + y[t]], t] + f'[x[t] + y[t]]}
```

This is:

[image]

The first equations claims: `x'[t] + y'[t]== -2(x[t]+y[t])`,  whereas the second claims: `x'[t] + y'[t]== -(x[t]+y[t])`